# Handy method to reverse the order of an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` and I want to flip it, i.e., reverse the order of the objects.

I can do that by making a for loop and moving all the objects. Is there some nice method or trick to do this another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSArray* reversedArray = [[originalArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

should do the trick